# finding Immersion points of the klein bottle?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, parametrization

i'm having problems to resolve this type of question,
So given $a>0$
i have $$\psi:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, (u,v) \rightarrow(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$$

where
$$x(u,v) = (a+cos(\frac{u}{2})sin(v)-sin(\frac{u}{2})sin(2v))cos(u)$$
$$y(u,v) = (a+cos(\frac{u}{2})sin(v)-sin(\frac{u}{2})sin(2v))sin(u)$$
$$z(u,v) = sin(\frac{u}{2})sin(v)+cos(\frac{u}{2})sin(2v)$$
The set $M = \psi(\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R})$ is a realization of the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Determine the points where $\psi$ is an immersion.

Comment: Do you mean the points where $\psi$ is *only* an immersion, i.e., where it is not an embedding?

Comment: yes, not embedding, only points where $\psi$ is an immersion